# Using C++ and Boost (or not?) to check if a specific port is being used?

Tags: c++, boost, port, listen

I am trying to check if a specific port is being used in C++. I am not trying to have the C++ program listen on that port for any reason, just check to see if it is being used. There will be another program listening on that port, and if it stops, I want my program to do something. So, it will check every 10 seconds or so, and if the port is in use, it will do nothing, but if the port becomes available, something will happen.

I've been looking at the boost ASIO library, but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two options here.

If you actually want to check the port is use, simply attempt a bind:

```
bool port_in_use(unsigned short port) {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using ip::tcp;

    io_service svc;
    tcp::acceptor a(svc);

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    a.open(tcp::v4(), ec) || a.bind({ tcp::v4(), port }, ec);

    return ec == error::address_in_use;
}
```

See it live: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5bd536dd9737247)</kbd>**, correctly printing

```
Port 1078 is in use
```

> **CAVEAT** there could be other reasons why you can't bind to a local endpoint; check that you have the required permissions first (the permission error is being swallowed here)

If you actually want to check that connections are being accepted, you will have to make a connection. This could be somewhat more time consuming so you might want to run this under a timeout:

```
bool accepting_connections(unsigned short port) {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using ip::tcp;
    using ec = boost::system::error_code;

    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        io_service svc;
        tcp::socket s(svc);
        deadline_timer tim(svc, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

        tim.async_wait([&](ec) { s.cancel(); });
        s.async_connect({{}, port}, [&](ec ec) {
                result = !ec; 
            });

        svc.run();
    } catch(...) { }

    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    if (accepting_connections(22))
        cout << "Port 22 is accepting connections\n";
}
```

Comment: In new boost asio you can use tcp::acceptor a(svc, {tcp::v4(), port}) in one line instead of call open and bind.

Answer (score 2):

Just as @sehe said, attempt to bind is a proper way.

```
a.bind({ tcp::v4(), port }, ec)
```

The method only detects if port is in use on `0.0.0.0:port`.

If you want to see if your program can listen on `127.0.0.1:port`(*they are different sockets*), try

```
a.bind(tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port), ec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version.

```
// addrinfo cleanup wrapper
// TCP  : AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP
// UDP  : AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP
// flag : 0 or AI_PASSIVE
addrinfo* ai_create(const std::string ip, const uint16_t port, int32_t family, int32_t socktype, int32_t protocol, int32_t flag)
{
    addrinfo* ai     = nullptr;
    addrinfo hint    = {};
    hint.ai_family   = family;
    hint.ai_socktype = socktype;
    hint.ai_protocol = protocol;
    hint.ai_flags    = flag;

    const char* sip = (ip == "") ? nullptr : ip.c_str();
    auto  pts = str(port);
    const char* spt = pts.c_str();
    int32_t ret = getaddrinfo(sip, spt, &hint, &ai);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        ai_delete(ai);
    }
    return ai;
}
#define ai_delete(p) {if ((p) != nullptr) { freeaddrinfo (p); (p) = nullptr; }}


// Stop IO and Close Complete
int32_t CLOSESOCKET(SOCKET sock)
{
    int32_t ret = 0;
    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        CancelIoEx((HANDLE)sock, nullptr);
        shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
        ret = closesocket(sock);
    }
    return ret;
}

// Port number is valid, not check avail
DllExport bool port_valid(const uint16_t port)
{
    return (port >= 0 && port <= UINT16_MAX) ? true : false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------


// Port usability check
// protocol : IPPROTO_TCP or IPPROTO_UDP
DllExport bool port_avail(const uint16_t port, int32_t protocol)
{
    bool ret = false;
    if (port_valid(port) && (protocol == IPPROTO_TCP || protocol == IPPROTO_UDP))
    {
        addrinfo* ai = nullptr;
        switch (protocol)
        {
            case IPPROTO_TCP:  ai = ai_create(string(""), port, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, protocol, AI_PASSIVE); break;
            case IPPROTO_UDP:  ai = ai_create(string(""), port, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM , protocol, AI_PASSIVE); break;
            default:break;
        }

        auto sock = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
        int32_t rst = ::bind(sock, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
        ret = (rst == 0) ? true : false;
        CLOSESOCKET(sock);
        ai_delete(ai);      
    }
    return ret;
}
```