# Check port availability with boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to check whether port on my pc is available or not. But this code crashes after the **acceptor.listen();**. Crash stack trace stops at:

```
 detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp
```

My code is:

```
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port);
        acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(false));
        acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor.listen();
    }
    catch (...) {
        // port busy
    }
```

How can I check this with boost or where is the problem in my code?

UPD1: I tried following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358321/using-c-and-boost-or-not-to-check-if-a-specific-port-is-being-used/33389163#33389163):

```
bool port_in_use(unsigned short port) {
using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;

    io_service svc;
    tcp::acceptor a(svc);

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    a.open(tcp::v4(), ec) || a.bind({ tcp::v4(), port }, ec);

    return ec == error::address_in_use;
}
```

but after function executes, my program crashes still in same place.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358321/using-c-and-boost-or-not-to-check-if-a-specific-port-is-being-used/33389163#33389163

Comment: Nope, crash at exiting from function still exist

Comment: What does that mean, @user2123079? What did you try? What function?

Comment: It would seem that the function is unrelated then. (How can it be "in the same place" though? The "same place" doesn't exist in that update.) Look for cases of UB elsewhere. Make it a SSCCE. See also *[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)* and *[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found how to do this in windows (from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int wmain()
{
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    clientService.sin_port = htons(27015);

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof (clientService));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    wprintf(L"Connected to server.\n");

    iResult = closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```